# How to stop brew downloading the formula each time when using services command

Tags: mac, command-line, homebrew

When I am using this command in macOS 13.2 to check the postgresql status:

```
➜  ~ brew services status postgresql
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.json
#############                                                             19.0%
```

Why does brew download the json when using local command, is it possible to close the download task? why download the whole json every time? what should I do to optimize the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1` in your shell rc file.

Also make sure the brew repos are on your disk:

```
brew tap homebrew/core
brew tap homebrew/cask
```